# Reactjs - Webpack Complie ERROR : Module build failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, compiler-errors

I'm a newbie to React. I've been following a React course on Udemy and I came up with an issue. The error is very clear and I tried to work it out but I couldn't identify what's wrong with my code.

This is my project Structure

[image: This is my project Structure]

This is the error which I'm getting in the console.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/video_list.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:8)

  3 | 
  4 | class VideoList extends Component{
> 5 |   const videoItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
    |         ^
  6 |     return <VideoListItem video={video} />
  7 |   });
  8 | 

 @ ./src/index.js 21:18-52
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is my source code for the errornous code which is 'video_list.js'

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

class VideoList extends Component{
  const videoItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem video={video} />
  });

  render(){
    return (
      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
        {videoItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoList;
```

I've imported and exported everything correctly. Because if I change the above code to this it works (compiles) perfectly fine and give the expected result.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

class VideoList extends Component{
  // const videoItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
  //   return <VideoListItem video={video} />
  // });

  render(){
    return (
      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
        {this.props.videos.length}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoList;
```

What have I gone wrong in my code ? What's wrong with my `videoItems` function.

This is regarding [this](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/) tutorial on udemy. In the course it's following component based structure. But as my preference I use class based structure (`class VideoList extends Component`)

Answer (score 0):

Moved `videoItems` function into `render()` function and solved the issue. It was a confusion.